# Why is the Firefox location bar so slow?

Tags: firefox, browser, awesomebar

I don't understand, Firefox is a great browser, but the location bar is so slow. It literally was stuck for 30 seconds looking up something in its database.

Is there a way to tell it to stop trying to be so smart about matching URLs?

(Edit: is there a way to limit the history so it purges old pages that have only been visited once, but it keeps pages that were visited multiple times?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find a couple of tips here [Firefox 3.5 Slow and Hangs After Typing a Few Letters in URL Location Bar](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/08/15/firefox-3-5-slow-and-hangs-after-typing-a-few-letters-in-url-location-bar/) around cleaning out your SQLLite places database.

Answer (score 7):

[Vacuum it!](http://www.oskaan.com/vacuum-your-firefox-databases-for-better-performance/)

There's an [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13878) to this automatically as well.

> Since Firefox 3.0, bookmarks, history
>   and most storage is kept in SQLite
>   databases. Also, the default history
>   time span was raised from 9 to 90 days
>   as it became more discoverable and
>   useful thanks to the awesome bar, so
>   depending on your browsing habits it
>   could represent some pretty large
>   databases.
>
> Aas any other database, SQLite
>   databases become fragmented over time
>   and empty spaces appear all around.
>   But, since there are no managing
>   processes checking and optimizing the
>   database, these factors eventually
>   result in a performance hit. So, a
>   good way to improve startup and some
>   other bookmarks and history related
>   tasks is to defragment and trim unused
>   space from these databases.

Answer (score 5):

`about:config`

`browser.urlbar.maxRichResults`

Set that to 0 and it'll stop searching (Or just set it lower and see if you can't get better performance out of it)

It's searching a HUGE database if it's taking 30 seconds, have you considered reducing your history length?

Comment: Not necessarily a huge database. I've seen performance to be pretty crappy on numerous systems already, sometimes even after a fresh install of FF.

Comment: Huh, maybe I'm just lucky? Searches still only take a few seconds and I have a good few months of hard browsing in there.

Comment: Turning off a (quite imporant) feature people use non-stop because it hogs the CPU is a silly way to go about it: the right way is to report bugs.